# A Feline with a high BMI

Tags: word, rhyme

Here is a special kind of riddle for you guys. 
You have to guess the two rhymes that will be described.
For example **a feline with a high BMI** is a *Fat Cat*.

> 1. A den or hideout where the Ursus species hang out
> 2. A horrible trend
> 3. A cruel prank
> 4. Someone who used to be an entertainer
> 5. A roaring mob
> 6. A king who is devoted and trustworthy
> 7. Mail by the ocean
> 8. A cream filled sponge cake that is smelly
> 9. A mushy and wet puppy

Comment: This was a fun one :) I might have to try this one myself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1.

> Bear Lair

2.

> Bad Fad

3.

> Sick Trick

4.

> Former Performer

5.

> Loud Crowd

6.

> Loyal Royal

7. via @JaapScherphuis (never entered my mind)

> Post Coast

8. via @Chowzen (I would have never thought of this!)

> Stinky Twinkie

9.

> Soggy Doggy

Comment: 7 rot13(jrggre yrggre)?
8. rot13(fgvaxl gjvaxl)?

Comment: For 7 I have "cbfg pbnfg" [rot13](http://rot13.com/)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yeah, that's probably _better_

Comment: You got them all! :D Great Job.

Comment: i'm not sure about #3 still - i guess i take that back. :)

Comment: thanks, @Laurel! I was trying to figure out *why* it was tabbed in... obvious now :)